# What is the execution order/logic : Task.Run( async() => await someAsyncMethod(); )

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

When reading 
[How to: Create Pre-Computed Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-create-pre-computed-tasks)
the example method `DownloadStringAsync` returns

```
Task.Run( async ()=> { return await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(address)})
```

I wonder why we need to wrap a async method in a `Task.Run()`? the `WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync()` method returns a `Task` itself.

Comment: We don't. That's a very specific example that needs to return a task that guarantees that the results are added to the cache before completing

Comment: Downvoters, that's a VALID QUESTION! This  documentation example is *not* a typical scenario

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - but I'm not seeing why that method itself couldn't be `async` itself and be far simpler without the `Task.Run` code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right ! they need to add content ( returned from WebClient async method) tp cache, so have to use "await" it. but in order to use await, it needs an async method, that is why there is lamda expression inside `Task.Run` !.   I just tried, if we do not need adding content to cache, we can directly write - > `return  new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(address)`;

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that's a question for the contributors to the article. It *is* a bit contrived to show how completed tasks can be used. And uses WebClient too.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is that they wanted to show how to use `Task.FromResult` and then tied themselves into knots because they wanted to consume a `Task` returning method.

The natural way these days to write code that consumes `Task` returning methods is to make them `async`. But then, if you do that, `Task.FromResult` disappears:

```
   // Asynchronously downloads the requested resource as a string.
   public static async Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(string address)
   {
      // First try to retrieve the content from cache.
      string content;
      if (cachedDownloads.TryGetValue(address, out content))
      {
         return content;
      }

      content = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(address);
      cachedDownloads.TryAdd(address, content);
      return content;
   }
```

Simpler code, still achieves the overall goal. Unless you expect `cachedDownloads.TryAdd` to be significantly CPU-heavy in which case their version also guarantees to push that into running in the thread pool.

**In short** - don't copy this code, it's not a good *example* to work from<sup>2</sup>.

---

This is the version that avoids allocating the `async` state machine<sup>1</sup> when not required, shows `Task.FromResult` and still doesn't use `Task.Run`:

```
   // Asynchronously downloads the requested resource as a string.
   public static Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(string address)
   {
      // First try to retrieve the content from cache.
      string content;
      if (cachedDownloads.TryGetValue(address, out content))
      {
         return Task.FromResult(content);
      }

      return DownloadStringSlowAsync(address);
   }
   private static async Task<string> DownloadStringSlowAsync(string address)
   {
      string content = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(address);
      cachedDownloads.TryAdd(address, content);
      return content;
   }
```

---

Even betterer: (no, it's not a word, I don't care)

```
   static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<string>> cachedDownloads =
   new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<string>>();
   // Asynchronously downloads the requested resource as a string.
   public static Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(string address)
   {
      // First try to retrieve the content from cache.
      Task<string> content;
      if (cachedDownloads.TryGetValue(address, out content))
      {
         return content;
      }

      return DownloadStringSlowAsync(address);
   }
   private static async Task<string> DownloadStringSlowAsync(string address)
   {
      string content = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(address);
      cachedDownloads.TryAdd(address, Task.FromResult(content));
      return content;
   }
```

Because now our cache only contains *completed* tasks and we can just hand them out over and over rather than repeatedly allocating new `Task` objects on every request.

Any of these approaches is, of course, only really viable if the cached objects (`string` here) are *immutable*.

---

<sup>1</sup>Don't do this automatically. It should be a deliberate, considered decision based upon whether such allocations are causing performance *issues*.

<sup>2</sup>It's *also* a bad example of a cache, since as Raymond Chen points out, [A cache with a bad policy is another name for a memory leak](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060502-07/?p=31333). In this example there's *no* expiration at all.

Comment: *Almost* - they avoid allocating a state machine *unless* the result is missing. But they do it using a WebClient. Oops

Comment: They could have done that by making the last 3 lines a separate method that was `async` and then we'd change this method to being non-async again and reintroduce `Task.FromResult`. We still wouldn't need `Task.Run`. (In modern C# we could even make it an async local method)

Comment: The article isn't even finished, check the non-existent `Robust Programming` section. Guess we need to provide some feedback in the new Github issue system ..

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - and if allocations are our concern, I offer variant 3 where the cache contains the completed `Task`s rather than the contents :-). It's terrible, I keep looking and finding tweaks I want to apply.

Comment: Started to comment and stopped 3 times already. It would take a lot of work to convert it to something that can be copied into production code. And my second thought was "memoization" which would derail the example completely

Comment: You can just remove the need for the async method entirely by using `GetOrAdd`, rather than making a method that does the work and then manipulates the cache.  `public static Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(string address) => cachedDownloads.GetOrAdd(address, _ => new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(address));`

Comment: @Servy - yep, more and more fixes are possible. But again, I think the problem is because they were trying to create a motivating example for `Task.FromResult` and then got lost in the trees with the example they came up with.

Comment: @Servy I think I've seen that in one of the earliest examples of GetOrAdd. Probably even in the Parallel Extensions Extras?

Comment: @Servy - one problem with `GetOrAdd`ing the download task to the cache is it may still be incomplete. If we have two callers racing, the original code lets them both try a request and add the *earliest* response to the cache. Adding the incomplete task to the cache means everyone's stuck waiting, even if that request was the unlucky one to hit a failing server that's taking time to timeout. (And in the event of failure, you don't have a *failed* `Task` in your cache)

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR don't use that example**. Except as an intellectual excercise. In fact, its current state shows it's unfinished, the [Robust Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-create-pre-computed-tasks#robust-programming) section is empty

**Long Version**

We don't, and the example is contrived.

The actual code does *not* just call `DownloadStringTaskAsync()`. The actual code is :

```
static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> cachedDownloads =
  new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

// Asynchronously downloads the requested resource as a string.
public static Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(string address)
{
  // First try to retrieve the content from cache.
  string content;
  if (cachedDownloads.TryGetValue(address, out content))
  {
     return Task.FromResult<string>(content);
  }

  // If the result was not in the cache, download the 
  // string and add it to the cache.
  return Task.Run(async () =>
  {
     content = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(address);
     cachedDownloads.TryAdd(address, content);
     return content;
  });
}
```

That's a very specific example that needs to return a task that guarantees that the results have already been cached.

That function makes HTTP calls asynchronoulsy with caching. This means it has to return a Task.

First, it checks whether the result is already available. If it is, it wrapped in a completed `Task` :

```
string content;
if (cachedDownloads.TryGetValue(address, out content))
{
   return Task.FromResult<string>(content);
}
```

Otherwise it returns a running task that makes the HTTP call and *ensures* the results are cached before returning them :

```
  // If the result was not in the cache, download the 
  // string and add it to the cache.
  return Task.Run(async () =>
  {
     content = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(address);
     cachedDownloads.TryAdd(address, content);
     return content;
  });
```

*The article is a bit contrived but has **other** benefits*

This article tries to show how to use completed tasks, although the example isn't as clear as it should. It has benefits that are *not* directly related to its subject.

For example, they avoid using `async/await` and that cost by returning a running task at athe end. The compiler will *not* generate the asynchronous state machine required for `async/await` methods unless the result is missing from the cache.

This means less allocations, and less IL complexity

But then they go and use the rather inefficient `WebClient` class ....

Comment: But even in the full example, there's no need at all for `Task.Run`.  You've demonstrated why there's a need for the async lambda.  There's no need to *start* that async method in a thread pool thread though, and wrap it in a `Task` *again*.

Comment: @Servy please don't. My hands are itching already. But I do know [someone that might be interested](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AddingCrossCuttingMemoryCachingToAnHttpClientFactoryInASPNETCoreWithPolly.aspx)